# How to get private user list of an org through github api

Tags: git, github, github-api

git api to get all users -
https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/members
(replaced :org with the organisation name)This gives all the list of the public users but not private.

Comment: Have you considered that _private_ users may be kept _private_ and not made accessible through a _public_ API?

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is possible with username and password or oauth token. See https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication
Username and password would be the right way if your app can ask the user for her/his credentials. If this is not possible (for example in batch mode) oauth would be the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The description of GitHub says

> List all users who are members of an organization. If the authenticated user is also a member of this organization then both concealed and public members will be returned.

So i guess this is the right behaviour as far as i understand it.

Comment: Yes! But is there any kind off authentication I can do through the api to get the private List?

Comment: @RiteshKumarReddyKuchukulla yes, It's called an access token. Checkout how I do it in my project: https://github.com/ConfusedDeer/Git-Captain